# Redirect all images from old domain to new domain with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, migration

I've redirected all the url's from my old domain vihara.nl to my new domain meditatieinstituut.nl. This is working fine, but it's not redirecting my images. For example see this image on vihara.nl: https://vihara.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/retraites.jpg

In .htaccess I used this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://meditatieinstituut.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In an other topic I found this code, which I tried to add but it's not doing anything:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?vihara\.nl$
RewriteRule ^(.+\.png|gif|pdf|jpg|doc)$ https://meditatieinstituut.com/$1 [NC,L,R]
```

Anyone an idea how I should do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is that supposed to be all you have in your .htaccess? I guess you probably have the usual RewriteConds before this, that make the rule apply only if the request did not match a physically existing file or folder.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Cbroe. This is all I have in the htaccess file:

#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://meditatieinstituut.nl/$1 [R=301,L] 


I'm not a programmer myself. Is it for you easy to write down the lines I should add?

Comment: If that is all you have in there, then it is unclear what would be causing this to begin with. What you have shown, does not appear to contain _any_ restrictions, so it should work the same for all URLs.

Comment: Ok, that's strange. You have any idea what might be the cause this is not working?

Comment: See for example https://vihara.nl/meditatieretraites/ this is working. But https://vihara.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/retraites.jpg is not.

Comment: Sorry, but with the .htaccess you have shown (the first version), there is no obvious explanation for this. Something else must be going on. (If you have full access to the server, then you could enable rewrite logging, maybe that could help figuring it out.)

Comment: I now used  
  
RewriteEngine on  
Redirect 301 / https://meditatieinstituut.nl/   
and this is working :)